# javascript split string of ints to array

Tags: javascript

I have a string MyString like this:

```
var MyString = "32,43,545,34,23,";
```

I'd like to have this in an array of ints.

If I do this:

```
var MyArray = MyString.split(",");
```

I get an array of strings. How do I get an array of ints?

I know I can loop over the array and do a parseInt on each element but I was wondering if there's a better way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're setting the contents why can't you make them an array initially?

Comment: Don't capitalize random variable names, use "camelCase".

Comment: @Rick: the string is the result of an ajax callback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

unfortunatelly you'll have to manually walk through the array and change each element like this:

```
var MyArray = MyString.split(",");
for (var i=0, LoopTimes = MyArray.length; i < LoopTimes; i++){
    MyArray[i] = parseInt(MyArray[i], 10);
}
```

or you can also have a look at this: http://phpjs.org/functions/array_walk:349

Comment: Don't forget the radix to `parseInt()` It's optional, but really it isn't.  `parseInt(MyArray[i], 10)`

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought of doing too. Oh well, no big biggie anyway.

Comment: I edited your answer to cache the length of the array and speed up the loop a bit. Thanks for your answer; I prefer cross-browser compatibility to something terser that works only in most browsers.

Answer (score 7):

```
'32,43,545,34,23'.split(',').map(Number)
```

Comment: I like it too, but it doesn't look like it's supported until in IE until 9. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility

Comment: For browsers not supporting ES5, you can use the excellent [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim).

Comment: "As closely as possible to ES5" is not very close. Many of these shims are intended only to allow code to be written to ES5 without causing run-time errors in older engines. In many cases, this means that these shims cause many ES5 methods to silently fail. Decide carefully whether this is what you want... Ouch... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/ maybe?

Comment: @Rick: Wait... If that statement from es5-shim is enough to dissuade someone, then how would jQuery be an improvement? `$.map` doesn't even *try* to be ES5 compatible.

Comment: Well, I pasted that comment from the readme and it seems I may have skimmed it too fast. For some reason I mistook fail silently for 'failing silently and not doing anything at all' instead of 'fail silently but go ahead and do what you expect to happen with this other function' I suppose it could actually be a decent library.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in most cases as well, and it is slightly faster than the parseInt method I believe.

```
for(var i=0;i<MyArray.length,i++){
  MyArray[i]=MyArray[i]-0;
}
```